# Drag GOJS node from palette and drop it in HTML div using Playwright

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, playwright, gojs

I want to drag and drop a node from the palette from GoJs to HTML div by Playwright.

```
    const { page } = this.helpers.Playwright;
    await page.mouse.move(x,y);
    await page.mouse.down();
    await page.mouse.move(xx, yy);
    await page.mouse.up();
```

The main problem is that Go.js palette is created inside the canvas dom element.
Is it even possible to do it with these technologies?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `robot.js` to simulate input like this: https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/Robot.html